# jQueryUI DatePicker 12 months view 'jumps' when clicked on date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to display and style a 12-month datepicker calendar with jquery-ui-1.8.17.
With help of [Styling the jQueryUI DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309194) the calendar initially shows fine, i.e. it shows a complete year in 3 rows, each row contains 4 months.
BUT, when i click on a day in the calendar, the display jumps to 1 line containing 12 months!
Anyone seeing this strange behaviour also or has a solution?

Note: in my code, i included jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css. This is file is generated with http://jqueryui.com/themeroller. See the links in the css file.

Here's the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://www.j2u.nl/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3982/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker ({
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
        firstDay: 1, // rows starts on Monday
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: '+1Y',
        numberOfMonths: 12
     });
     $(".ui-datepicker-inline").width("850px");
     $(".ui-widget").css("font-size","0.9em");
     });
  </script>         
</head>
<body>
     <p><div class="datepicker"></div></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post an example or the rest of your code including CSS. I threw up what you posted on  jsFiddle and get one long row of months.

Comment: Added the complete code now! Also as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7pEe/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, 5 minutes after posting the question to the jquery-ui bug list, someone answered it.
Basically numberOfMonths: [3,4] and the added style did the trick:

```
<style>.ui-widget { font-size: 62.5% }</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker ({
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
    firstDay: 1, // rows starts on Monday
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+1Y',
    numberOfMonths: [3,4]
 });
 });
```

Comment: Actually it does not helps. I have 2 months in 2 columns and I set NumberOfMonths: [2,1] and then NumberOfMonths: [2,1] none of them is working