# jQuery Calendar's CSS font-size issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, calendar

The calendar dropdown in DatePicker is taking the font size of the document rather than the div inside which the DatePicker resides. How do we fix this?

We don't want to apply the font size manually on the Calendar, because our solution is customizable and we want to allow other widgets with dropdowns as well and so we cannot forsee all dropdowns that might be shown.

```
#datepickerParent
{
    font-size:100px;
}

body
{
    font-size:15px;
}

<div id="datepickerParent">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</div>
<input type="text" id="dateInput" />

 $(function () {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
     $("#dateInput").datepicker();
 })
```

the calendar always takes 15px as its font-size.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fW6U8/2/)

Comment: duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309194/styling-the-jqueryui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Apply style to the `ui-datepicker` class or `ui-widget` class

```
.ui-datepicker{
    font-size:10px;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fW6U8/12/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code:

```
.ui-state-default
{
    font-size:10px !important;
}
```